# Auto Submit Contact Form 7

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

I’m looking for solution whole day but can’t find anything that work. So I want to automaticaly submit CF7 on page load. If I use any jQuery or JS solution there is some endless looping on the site. So any solution for my problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call **submit()** function on **document ready**
check the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#wpcf7-f3857-o1 form").submit();
});
</script>
```

In my code **wpcf7-f3857-o1** is the contact form's css id.
You need to change that id.
try the code and let me know the result.
Thanks

Comment: This cause endless looping. Page doesn't have time to render because this script submit form again and again :(

Comment: I'm adding this in functions-php as a shortcode and then place shortcode after cf7.

add_shortcode('custom_js_for_cf7','custom_js_for_cf7');
function custom_js_for_cf7($args){
return '
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("#wpcf7-f3857-o1 form").submit();
});
</script>
';
}

I'm I doing something wrong?